# VERBOSE=yes makefile option on gnu make under cygwin not working for me

Tags: cygwin, gnu-make

I use gnumake version GNU Make 3.81 under cygwin on windows. Cygwin version is CYGWIN_NT-6.1-WOW64 1.7.7(0.230/5/3) 2010-08-31 09:58 i686 Cygwin

In my makefile used to build the source, when i say VERBOSE=yes, i still do not see detailed commands and options used to compile,link the code. So basically VEROBSE=yes behaviour seems to be same as VERBOSE=no. 
Pls. note that the compiler (sparc-elf-gcc) which the make command invokes, is configured with --verbose option. I verified that by checking sparc-elf-gcc -v .

Is this switch removed/deprecated for this particular gnumake/cygwin versions or any pointers on how I can see details of the make/compile/link commands.

thank you.

-AD.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The verbose options are not symetrical. If you turn them off in one place they are off and can not be turned on somewhere else.

Have you a @ in front of your commands? This also makes commands silent.

Answer (score 1):

I think this could help you :

```
make VERBOSE=1
```

It will show the details of the compilator commands

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

> make V=1

It works in Linux with GNU Make 3.82